# Is this transformation of Beal's conjecture valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Beal's conjecture is:

> If 
>   $$ x^a + y^b = z^c \ \ \ \ (1) $$
>   where $a,b,c, x,y,z$ are positive integers with  $a,b,c \gt 2,$  then $x,y,z $ have a common prime factor.

(copied from Wikipedia)

Now, if Beal's conjecture is true, then there are no such integers satisfying $(1)$ and $rx + sz  =1$, for some $r,s \in \Bbb{Z}$.  The converse is also true by contrapositive:  if Beal is not true, then there is a coprime solution $\gcd(x,y,z) \neq 1 \implies \gcd(x,z) \neq 1 \implies rx + sz = 1 $ for some $r,s \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Now let's work with this new formulation.  If a counter-example to Beal exists, then
$$
x^a + y^b = (\frac{1 - rx}{s})^c   \ \  \  \ \  (2)
$$
has in integer solution with $r,s \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Conversely if $(2)$ has an integer solution then there's a counter-example to Beal's.  So Beal's conjecture is equivalent to:

> There are no integer solutions to 
>   $$x^a + y^b = (\frac{1-rx}{s})^c
> $$
>   such that $a,b,c \gt 2, \ \ x,y,z \gt 0$.

Is that correct?

Comment: You typed in the conjecture incorrectly. I fixed it.

Comment: You may need to change other bits. Note that what you did, compared to wikipedia, was to switch abc with xyz.

Comment: Yes, it is. The only problem is $x,y,z>1$.The case where either $x,y,$ or z$ is allowed be $1$ has already been proven.